# How to Http Post with Json Body on Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to get data from API. I need to pass value from the body, in postman without a header: application/JSON data is not displayed.

```
final response = await http.post(
      "http://192.168.10.25:8080/Login/validateusername",
    body: {"username": "user@PYA"},
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    );
```

Error Message:

```
E/flutter (28851): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(184)] Dart Error: Unhandled exception:
E/flutter (28851): Bad state: Cannot set the body fields of a Request with content-type "application/json".
```

[image]

Comment: The question should contain the code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish and what you tried. Also please explain what the actual and the expected results are.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Do you have a solution for my question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the content type  `application/json`

```
Future<String> apiRequest(String url, Map jsonMap) async {
  HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
  HttpClientRequest request = await httpClient.postUrl(Uri.parse(url));
  request.headers.set('content-type', 'application/json');
  request.add(utf8.encode(json.encode(jsonMap)));
  HttpClientResponse response = await request.close();
  // todo - you should check the response.statusCode
  String reply = await response.transform(utf8.decoder).join();
  httpClient.close();
  return reply;
}
```

Comment: Error: Bad state: Cannot set the body fields of a Request with content-type "application/json".

Comment: it's working...But return value is srting..how to get one by one passing value

Comment: You can change  String to whatever your desired requirement is

Comment: can to tell me how to do it

Comment: I have model class for my json...my json looki like this, {user{"name":"abc"}}

Comment: How to validate? can to give example? I used your method. It's working very well. But when connection lost error message coming. hOW TO VALIDATE?

Answer (score 6):

Simply encode body to json object when using content-type "application/json"

```
http.Response response = await http.post( uri , headers: headers, body: JsonEncoder().convert(body));
```

Answer (score 5):

Another simple way is as bellow

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

String body = json.encode({
    'foo': 'bar',
    'complex_foo' : {
        'name' : 'test'     
    }
});

http.Response response = await http.post(
    url: 'https://example.com',
    headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
    body: body,
);
```

Answer (score 3):

use the http dart package

```
var data = {username:"username",password:"password"};
 http.Response response = await http.post(
        "yourApiroute",
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
        body: {"username": data.phone, "password": data.password});
```

Comment: Error: Dart Error: Unhandled exception:
E/flutter (26853): Bad state: Cannot set the body fields of a Request with content-type "application/json".

Answer (score 0):

```
var json = jsonCodec.encode(data);
    print("json=$json");
    var url = "http:yourAPIrouter.com/etc";
    var response = await http.post(
      url,
      headers:{ "Accept": "application/json" } ,
      body: { "json": '$json'},
      encoding: Encoding.getByName("utf-8")
    );
```

> and dont forget add the key `"json"` in postman

[image]

Comment: I can't change my backend

Comment: and also you can try                                                            Map toJson() {
    return {"username" : _username,"password" : _pass};
  }

Comment: i want to use Raw not form-data

Comment: You can use Raw if you want to send plain text or JSON or any other kind of string. Like the name suggests, Postman sends your raw string data as it is without modifications, you can use this example to post.

Comment: I am not creating back-end.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing almost the same. However, I tried to avoid doing back-end, like in your case. I just did a minimal php request so that I would not waste or patience learning what is needed to develop a user management controller.

However, I faced several limitations and problems that Flutter alone can't solve. After some denial, I gave a try. Lumen, a light version of the Laravel Framework, some tutorials and some past experience, I eventually realized that the API should carry most of the authentication, and not the application itself. I digressed.

In my case, the code of the fuction to a http post is:

```
Future<Post> createPost() async {
final url = "http://localhost:8000/api/login";
Map<String, String> body = {
  'user': user.text,
  'pass': pass.text,
};
await http.post(url, body: body);
print(body);

return http.;
```

}

I first convert it into a map. I prefer this method over parsing json, because down the line, if I need to add more variables, I just make the map bigger.

I just have a question: What does your http://192.168.10.25:8080/Login/validateusername look like? I think that there is no need to specify the type of information that your body parses.