# How to pass dynamic array to PHP script through POST

Tags: flutter

I want to pass entire a dynamic array to PHP script via POST. This is my code:

```
final items = ["1", "2", "3"];// Its dynamic with different length depends on the user input

_save() async{
    final response = await http.post(
        "http://myip/Flutter/insert.php",
        body:json.encode({
            "arraydata" :items.toString(),
        }
    ));

    print(response.body);
}
```

In the insert.php my code is:

```
$array = $_POST['arraydata'];

foreach( $array as $key ) {

$result = $connect->query("UPDATE users SET post='A' WHERE username = '$key'");

if($result){
    echo "success";
} else {
    echo "error";}
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Undefined index: arraydata
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't call `json.encode()` or you probably would have to call `json_decode($_POST)` in PHP, but I am not sure whether that would work.
Just call it like so:

`final response =await http.post("http://myip/Flutter/insert.php", body( {...} ))`

Comment: I got it with the help of @Adonis González solution at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54996674/how-to-http-post-with-json-body-on-flutter

Comment: @raj So you could post your working code as an answer here and mark it as accepted ... Would help others.